# Stop redirection to non local domain globally in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, config, global-asax

Is it possible to stop all redirection to non local domains globally? For example if my application website is www.mysite.com/index.aspx and if somewhere in the application the code is trying to redirect to www.google.com I need to block it.

Is it possible to do it globally (maybe in the global.asax file)? Can we add some domains in the config file that are allowed and block everything else?

What's the best way to achieve this?

I can write a helper method to stop redirection but then I will have to call this method every time for a redirection.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the redirection from the application? I'm confused.

Comment: This is an application that we are maintaining. There are many instances where there is a redirect. In one instance a url is being passed as a parameter and anyone can change that url and that is what we are trying to avoid.

Comment: Can't you filter the parameter before using it for redirection? My point is, you can't stop redirecting to an external site because there's no request coming into your application to handle it (it's external). You'd have to modify the `Redirect()` method which isn't going to happen, so you're kind of stuck with filtering what you pass into the `Redirect()` method.

Comment: I guess that's basically what my question if it is possible to control this. If not then I guess the only solution we have is to filter the parameter (url) before redirect.

Comment: What about url rewrite? Is that something we can use?